# Debian iptables: Block all Incoming except special IPs or Ports

Tags: iptables, debian-wheezy

I play around with the rules for my web server, but it doesn´t work as i want. The ports seems to be reachable, but a connection won´t happen, here´s the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Drop all Incoming
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

# Allow all Outgoing
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

# Allow Incoming for special IPs to all Ports
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 2.3.4.5/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 3.4.5.6/32 -j ACCEPT

# Allow Incoming from Internet to Ports
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Your first rule drops all incoming packets. Even those looping back to the host itself. There is no way anything is ever going to work when your firewall rules won't let even one single packet pass.

Comment: thanks for hinting me to the right position...working 3 days in a row makes blind.^^changing the first rule to iptables --policy INPUT DROP solves it!

Comment: @Daniel, please take the time to write this out as an answer, don't correct the mistake in the question. Please read the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple, just replace the first rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

with

```
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
```

This doesn't block all, instead sets the policy to default block for Input connections.